# scale animation overlaps beyond frame of parents view

Tags: android, animation, gridview, parent-child

I scale a cardview with an image view inside. It runs correctly. The cardview is an element of a convert view within a gridview. There is a space between the cardview and the frame of the convert view, that a scale can be possible.

but: the scale animation should scale beyond the frame of the convert view, that the scale is bigger (there is a space of the neighbor convert view, too). The scale animation should use the space of the neighbor convert view to be bigger.

the scale value is ok, and the Animation scales, but when the cardview scales beyond the convert view, the images are cutted and only visible until the convert view frames. beyond the frames the images are no longer visible, within the frames the are visible.

Short question: my scale animation should scale over the boarders of the parents convert view (or a parents view generally). but the images are cutted beyond the borders.

is there a XML value (like a scale value) to make the images visible, when scaled over the parents boarders.

i will try to scale the whole convert view, but isn't it dirty?

thanks!